# Getting "define cannot be used indirect" error when bundling with Webpack

Tags: webpack, requirejs, amd

When I try to bundle my code written in AMD I get the error `Uncaught Error: define cannot be used indirect` as soon as I use the `define()` function. How can I solve this? It is not an option to change the `define()` to `import` since the whole project is written in RequireJS AMD

This is my Webpack configuration:

```
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        app: './app/js/app/main.js'
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'app/build'),
        filename: 'main.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [{
            test: /\.js?$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            query: {
                presets: ['@babel/env']
            }
        }]
    }
};
```

My entry file:

```
define('app', [
    'lib/angular',
    'lib/has',
], function (angular, has) {
    'use strict';

    return angular.module('app', ['ngAnimate', 'ngSanitize', 'angular-require'])

}, function(error) {
    console.error(error);
});
```

This is the output it is giving me:

```
!function (e) {
    var n = {};

    function r(t) {
        if (n[t]) return n[t].exports;
        var o = n[t] = {i: t, l: !1, exports: {}};
        return e[t].call(o.exports, o, o.exports, r), o.l = !0, o.exports
    }

    r.m = e, r.c = n, r.d = function (e, n, t) {
        r.o(e, n) || Object.defineProperty(e, n, {enumerable: !0, get: t})
    }, r.r = function (e) {
        "undefined" != typeof Symbol && Symbol.toStringTag && Object.defineProperty(e, Symbol.toStringTag, {value: "Module"}), Object.defineProperty(e, "__esModule", {value: !0})
    }, r.t = function (e, n) {
        if (1 & n && (e = r(e)), 8 & n) return e;
        if (4 & n && "object" == typeof e && e && e.__esModule) return e;
        var t = Object.create(null);
        if (r.r(t), Object.defineProperty(t, "default", {
            enumerable: !0,
            value: e
        }), 2 & n && "string" != typeof e) for (var o in e) r.d(t, o, function (n) {
            return e[n]
        }.bind(null, o));
        return t
    }, r.n = function (e) {
        var n = e && e.__esModule ? function () {
            return e.default
        } : function () {
            return e
        };
        return r.d(n, "a", n), n
    }, r.o = function (e, n) {
        return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(e, n)
    }, r.p = "", r(r.s = 0)
}([function (e, n, r) {
    var t;
    void 0 === (t = function () {
        "use strict";
        r(1)("app", ["lib/angular", "lib/has"], function (e, n) {
            return e.module("app", ["ngAnimate", "ngSanitize", "angular-require"])
        }, function (e) {
            console.error(e)
        })
    }.apply(n, [])) || (e.exports = t)
}, function (e, n) {
    e.exports = function () {
        throw new Error("define cannot be used indirect")
    }
}]);
```

However the entry file is being imported by the RequireJS config file:

```
var bower_components = bower_components || 'bower_components';

require.config({
    paths: {
        'lib/angular': bower_components + '/angular/angular.min',
        'lib/angular-animate': bower_components + '/angular-animate/angular-animate.min',
        'lib/sprintf': bower_components + '/sprintf/dist/sprintf.min',
        'lib/twitter-text': bower_components + '/twitter-text-js/js/twitter-text',
        'lib/jsdiff': bower_components + '/jsdiff/diff',
        es6: "lib/requirejs-babel/es6",
        babel: "lib/requirejs-babel/babel-5.8.34.min",
        'babel-plugin-module-resolver': 'lib/babel-plugin-module-resolver-standalone/index'
    },
    babel:{
        fileExtension: ".js"
    },
    packages: [{
            name: 'app',
            location: 'build' //This directs to the file compiled by webpack
        }, {
            name: 'app/blogLegacy',
            location: 'apps/blog-legacy'
        },{
            name: 'app/blog',
            location: 'apps/blog-modular'
        },{
```

EDIT

Full error:

```
Uncaught Error: define cannot be used indirect
    at module.exports (webpack:///(webpack)/buildin/amd-define.js?:2:8)
    at eval (main.js:1)
    at Object../app/js/app/main.js (main.js?bust=1558595950937:96)
    at __webpack_require__ (main.js?bust=1558595950937:20)
    at main.js?bust=1558595950937:84
    at main.js?bust=1558595950937:87
module.exports @ amd-define.js:2
(anonymous) @ main.js:1
./app/js/app/main.js @ main.js?bust=1558595950937:96
__webpack_require__ @ main.js?bust=1558595950937:20
(anonymous) @ main.js?bust=1558595950937:84
(anonymous) @ main.js?bust=1558595950937:87
angular.js:38 

Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.20/$injector/modulerr?p0=app&p1=Error%3A%20%5B%24injector%3Anomod%5D%20http%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.3.20%2F%24injector%2Fnomod%3Fp0%3Dapp%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Fgo.development%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3Fbust%3D1558595950937%3A6%3A417%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Fgo.development%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3Fbust%3D1558595950937%3A21%3A412%0A%20%20%20%20at%20a%20(http%3A%2F%2Fgo.development%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3Fbust%3D1558595950937%3A21%3A53)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Fgo.development%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3Fbust%3D1558595950937%3A21%3A296%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Fgo.development%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3Fbust%3D1558595950937%3A35%3A46%0A%20%20%20%20at%20r%20(http%3A%2F%2Fgo.development%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3Fbust%3D1558595950937%3A7%3A322)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20g%20(http%3A%2F%2Fgo.development%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3Fbust%3D1558595950937%3A34%3A399)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20cb%20(http%3A%2F%2Fgo.development%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3Fbust%3D1558595950937%3A38%3A135)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20d%20(http%3A%2F%2Fgo.development%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3Fbust%3D1558595950937%3A17%3A381)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20tc%20(http%3A%2F%2Fgo.development%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3Fbust%3D1558595950937%3A18%3A179)
    at angular.js:38
    at angular.js:4154
    at r (angular.js:326)
    at g (angular.js:4115)
    at cb (angular.js:4041)
    at d (angular.js:1455)
    at tc (angular.js:1476)
    at Jd (angular.js:1370)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (angular.js:26446)
    at j (jquery.js:3148)
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you have some modules dependencies which are using `define` in a strange way (do not use the standard umd boilerplate).

You will have to find which one is the dependency with the problem and then do something like this in your webpack config for that lib:

```
module: {
    noParse: /node_modules\/json-schema\/lib\/validate\.js/
}
```

Some known modules with this issue: `set-getter`, `jquery-migrate`, `Dexie`

There are also a lot of issues opened on webpack github page:
https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/138
https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/2958
https://github.com/doowb/set-getter/issues/1

Comment: Just to be safe, I removed all node modules, reduced my `package.json` to 
    `"@babel/core": "^7.4.4",`
   `"@babel/preset-env": "^7.4.4",`
    `"babel-loader": "^8.0.5",`
    `"webpack": "^4.30.0",`
    `"webpack-dev-server": "^3.3.1",`
    `"webpack-cli": "^3.3.2"`

And ran yarn install again. Compiled the webpack file but I am still getting the same error.

Comment: What do you mean? Those are all the packages I am using plus the default modules that npm uses. And then there are bower_components and a lib directory which worked before integrating webpack.

Comment: I editted my question to contain the full error in case it is of any help.

Comment: The error does disappear if I put `noParse: /node_modules/` so I think you are right. I just don't know which module causes it.

Comment: I would try to remove dependencies one by one, just to see which one has that problem, and then use that in no parse...